# C++ application that receives JSON and writes to database

Tags: c++

I guess this is a novice question, but here goes anyway...

How do I get an application running on a machine to send data to another application running on a remote server which processes this data and writes it to a database? I would like to also authenticate the incoming data as well

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You basically need the following components in your application:

- network communication module (client/server)
- JSON parser/encoder
- authentication module
- database access module

For excellent C++ network library have a look at [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html), there are many examples how to use it.

For JSON library there is a Boost-based [JSON Spirit](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/JSON_Spirit.aspx)

Simple authentication can be achieved with [HMAC signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hmac) (for example using OpenSSL library)